# Disable file acess within webview without disabling file upload

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to disable file URL access within webview such that webview should not able to load files like-

```
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
```

For that I can use `setAllowFileAccess(false);`
But I don’t want to disable file upload feature inside webview done using openFileChooser,onShowFileChooser.

Will putting `setAllowFileAccess(false)` affects file upload feature inside webview also?

Comment: Well what prevents you to try such?

Comment: @blackapps I tried and found onShowFileChooser getting called even with setAllowFileAccess(false)

Comment: Does that answer your question?